# ¿Cómo le hago para sumarle un valor tipo "Int" a dos variables tipo "Int" en un solo paso?

Tags: python

Algo así intenté:

```
> a = 2
> b = 2
> a, b += 2
```

Me da error pero lo que yo deseo como resultado es que a ambas variables se les sume 2 con el valor que tenían y que al mencionarlas me de 4 las dos.

```
> a, b
> (4, 4)
```

Comment: `a, b = a+2, b+2`

Comment: La mejor forma built-in es la que Abulafia propuso. Si esa solucion no te gusta, tendras que crear una funcion que haga ese trabajo. Eso de convertir cientos de pasos en uno solo usando funciones y/o OOP es la base misma de la programacion.